# Calling a method in another to populate an array

Tags: java, fizzbuzz

I would like to start by saying that it's been a couple years since I coded so my knowledge is a little shaky. I'm looking for some help, basically a push in the right direction.
I am tasked with completing a program for a variation of the FizzBuzz game, The rules are:
Enter 2 digits from 1-9, a Fizz number and a buzz number (ex: 2  7 )

- if n is divisible by fizzNumber, or contains the digit fizzNumber, return "fizz"
- if n is divisible by buzzNumber, or contains the digit buzzNumber, return "buzz"
- however, if both the above conditions are true, you must return "fizzbuzz"
- if none of the above conditions is true, return the number itself.

So i got that part down, my code is as follows, and it compiles correctly.

```
public String getValue(int n) {

boolean fz = false;     //fz will symbolize fizz in my logic
boolean bz = false;    //bz will symbolize buzz in my logic

//if n is divisible by fizzNumber, or contains the digit fizzNumber, return "fizz"
    if(n % fizzNumber == 0 || Integer.toString(n).contains(Integer.toString(fizzNumber)))
    fz = true;

//if n is divisible by buzzNumber, or contains the digit buzzNumber, return "buzz"
    if(n % buzzNumber == 0 || Integer.toString(n).contains(Integer.toString(buzzNumber))) //Check for buzz
    bz = true;

//if both the above conditions are true, you must return "fizzbuzz"
if (fz == true && bz == true)
    return("fizzbuzz");
 //return fizz
    else if (fz == true)
    return("fizz");
//return buzz
    else if(bz == true)
    return("buzz");
// return the number itself as a String
    else
    return Integer.toString(n); 
}
```

Now my next goal is to implement the `getValues()` method, to return an array of fizzbuzz values for a given range of integers. This method should internally call the `getValue()` method to compute the fizzbuzz value of a single integer, and store it to an array that is to be returned in the end.

```
public String[] getValues(int start, int end) {
        }
```

For example, if the fizz number is 3 and buzz number is 4, getValues(2,7) should return an array of Strings:

```
  {"2", "fizz", "buzz", "5", "fizz", 7}
```

I'm thinking of doing this with a for loop with something like this

```
for(start = 0; end >= start; start ++){

    }
```

but i really don't know how to implement the getValue method into my loop and store it in an array.

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    public String[] getValues(int start, int end) {
        List<String> valueList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            valueList.add(getValue(i));
        }
        String[] valueArr = new String[valueList.size()];
        valueArr = valueList.toArray(valueArr);
        return valueArr;
    }
```

Comment: So when you write getValue(i) that is taking i and passing it through the get value method?,

Comment: yes, getValue(i) calls your first method with i as the input.

Comment: Instead of just providing the answer, it would be much helpful if you can explain what is happening and why, throughout a solution. In that way, people will not be dependent on you for the next time, right? :)

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the result you want. You want to do the combined condition first or else it will never be reached. If the number is divisible by both, and reaches one of the other statements first, it will always evaluate to true and never reach the combined condition unless its first.

```
public String[] getValues(int start, int end) {
    List<String> vals = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        if (i % (fizzNumber * buzzNumber) == 0) vals.add("fizzbuzz");
        else if (i % fizzNumber == 0) vals.add("fizz");
        else if (i % buzzNumber == 0) vals.add("buzz");
        else vals.add(i.toString());
    }

    return vals.toArray();
}


int fizzNumber = 3;
int buzzNumber = 5;
String[] arr = getValues(10, 20);
// ["buzz", "11", "fizz", "13", "14", "fizzbuzz", "16", "17", "fizz", "19", "buzz"]
```

Comment: This is certainly one way to do it, but it doesn't call the other method. However this is still useful for learning how to populate an array, whilst running through the logic. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

You almost got your homework done! The function is below with comments.

```
public String[] getValues(int start, int end) {
    // create the storage list
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=start; i<=end; i++){
        // append the string to the list
        words.add(getValue(i));
    }
    //return the stored words as String[]
    return words.toArray();
}
```

Comment: First, thanks for the reply. So, when you input getValue(i) that is taking i and running it through the getValue method?

Comment: This method will give you compiler error, should not be the correct answer, please see my answer to run without any error.

Comment: Yes @maxbr7t , it does.